# Getting position of mouse click in a QLabel

Tags: c++, qt, point-of-sale, mousepress

What is the best (as in simplest) way to obtain the `pos` of a `mousePressedEvent` in a QLabel? (Or basically just obtain the location of a mouse click relative to a QLabel widget)

**EDIT**

I tried what Frank suggested in this way:

```
bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *someOb, QEvent *ev)
{
if(someOb == ui->label && ev->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress)
{
    QMouseEvent *me = static_cast<QMouseEvent *>(ev);
    QPoint coordinates = me->pos();
    //do stuff
    return true;
}
else return false;
}
```

However, I receive the compile error `invalid static_cast from type 'QEvent*' to type 'const QMouseEvent*'` on the line where I try to declare `me`. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could subclass QLabel and reimplement mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent*). Or use an event filter:

```
bool OneOfMyClasses::eventFilter( QObject* watched, QEvent* event ) {
    if ( watched != label )
        return false;
    if ( event->type() != QEvent::MouseButtonPress )
        return false;
    const QMouseEvent* const me = static_cast<const QMouseEvent*>( event );
    //might want to check the buttons here
    const QPoint p = me->pos(); //...or ->globalPos();
    ...
    return false;
}


label->installEventFilter( watcher ); // watcher is the OneOfMyClasses instance supposed to do the filtering.
```

The advantage of event filtering is that is more flexible and doesn't require subclassing. But if you need custom behavior as a result of the received event anyway or already have a subclass, its more straightforward to just reimplement fooEvent().

Comment: Do you really need 2 `const`'s in the declaration of me? If so, why? Also, I am having trouble compiling your code as the compiler gives me `invalid static_cast from type 'QEvent*' to type 'const QMouseEvent*'` on that line

Comment: Did you include <QMouseEvent>? The consts are not strictly necessary, but I consider it good practice to make temporaries const.

Comment: ah yes, I didn't include that. Thanks! What I was wondering though was why it wasn't just `const QMouseEvent * me`... what does the second const do?

Comment: The first const makes the object const, the second makes the pointer itself const.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem

> invalid static_cast...

I just forgot to include the header: `#include "qevent.h"`

Now everything is working well.