# problem with QMouseEvent in QRect

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, qt

OS::win_xp_sp3

Qt::4.6

Is it possible to use QMouseEvent inside QRect?
I have parent widget and inside is some QLabel with text "status unchanged".

Also , inside parent widget is MyRect which is derived from QRect.

Now I want to MouseEvent act only inside this MyRect. For example , if I act on MyRect , text in parent widget need to be changed.

For example:

```
class MyRect : public QRect  {
      public:
      MyRect(int x, int y, int w, int h, ParentWidget* parent)
            : QRect(x,y,w,h) 
            {
               itsParent = parent;
            }
      ~MyRect() {}

      protected:
      void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent* event)  

      private:
      ParentWidget* itsParent

  };  

void MyRect::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
{
    if(event->buttons() == Qt::LeftButton)
    {
        itsparent->label->setText("status changed");
    }

}
```

nothing happens

question:: is it possible to use QMouseEvent like this (only on QRect)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A QRect is neither a QObject nor a QWidget, so it doesn't receive events.
It's just four numbers describing a rectangle (and it doesn't make sense to derive from it).
You can check if a point is the given rect in the mouse event handler of your widget. Like:

```
void MyLabel::mouseMoveEvent( QMouseEvent* e ) {
    if ( !rect.contains( e->pos() ) )
        return;
    //... handle mouse move
}
```

An alternative to subclassing is [using an event filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353175/getting-position-of-mouse-click-in-a-qlabel/4354194#4354194).

Answer (score 2):

> is it possible to use QMouseEvent like this (only on QRect)?

No, at least not how you do it. [QRect](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qrect.html) is not a [QWidget](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qwidget.html) and therefore doesn't have any `mouseEvent` handlers and such. It is just an entity with four coordinates.

You can do what you want by adding a handler to a real QWidget (either by subclassing, or using `installEventFilter`) and in the handler check for clicking in your rectangle using `QRect::contains(QPoint)`.