# Qt4: QLabel -> QPixmap -> click to open URL

Tags: qt, qt4, hyperlink, qpixmap, qlabel

I have a QLabel without any text but with a QPixmap image. I can not figure out a way to open a url when the user clicks the image. I can not use text in QLabel here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to put text in, but you do need to switch to either a subclassed label or to use a QPushButton instead.  If you use a QPushButton (which is the easiest) then you can change the relief layout so it looks flat again (since the default button doesn't).

Comment: Thanks, I set the push button to flat, set the icon as the image, manually set the image size (width, height) and then joined it to the URL opening slot

Answer (score 1):

You could install an event filter on the label and filter for mouse press events. For an example, see [my answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353175/getting-position-of-mouse-click-in-a-qlabel/4354194#4354194).